# Is it required to write custom matchers for this Mockito situation?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I have the following situation... I want to throw an exception whenever a particular method is called.  I don't care what is passed in to this method, I just want an exception to be called.  The catch is that this method takes custom classes as parameters.

The only way I have found to do this is with the following:

```
// Matches any Foo
TypeSafeMatcher<Foo> fooMatcher = new TypeSafeMatcher<Foo>() {
  @Override
  public Boolean matchesSafely(Foo foo) {
    return true;
  }

  // more overrides
}

doThrow(new RuntimeException("dummy exception")).when(mockObj).someMethod(fooMatcher);
```

I tried doing the following, but I'm getting a message similar to "can't convert Object to Foo"... which makes sense:

```
doThrow(new RuntimeException("dummy exception")).when(mockObj).someMethod(anyObject());
```

I'm wondering if there is an easier way to do this without having to create a custom matcher for each custom class?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried the isA matcher?

```
doThrow(new RuntimeException("dummy exception")).when(mockObj).someMethod(isA(Foo.class));
```

Answer (score 2):

A cast may suffice:

```
doThrow(new RuntimeException("dummy exception")).when(mockObj).someMethod((Foo)anyObject());
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also doAnswer() if you want to do something different than raising an exception

```
doAnswer(new Answer() {
      public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
          Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
          Mock mock = invocation.getMock();
          return null;
      }})
  .when(mock).someMethod();
```